# C# Integration to ZohoCRM

Tags: c#

I am learning C# SDK to Zoho CRM to Integrate 2 platforms. And keep getting this error
"The **ZCRMRestClient** name does not exist in the context" and "The **ZohoOAuthTokens** name does not exist in the context".

I already added the necessary NuGets in my project and configure the **app.config** for the added files. I read the Zoho C# SDK documentation but I have a hard time understanding it.

This is the Record Class
[image: Record Class]

The added configurations in my app.config

App.Config
[image: App.config]

Comment: So, did you find an answer to this problem? Cause I have the same problem as you, I can not create a record, because they are using ZCRMRecord, which I don't have.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't use the ZCRMClient library. I used the HTTP Request of C#.